# Send / Recieve WebService CURL

Tags: curl

I have been looking in so many post about how does CURL works and I can surely affirm that, I have no clue why my CURL command line does not get response.

Well, let me introduce my problem. To this project I have the urge to send via remotely from "Servoy" (web-developer tool) a file to a WebService and then, read the response.

The input file is generated easily and have the correct form 'cos I can check it in the Portal Test.

```
URL=$(curl --connect-timeout 60 -m 60 -s -S -L --cacert ./cacert.pem --cert ./certificado_12.pem --key ./certificado_key.pem -d "@BCE2_recibidas_consulta.xml" -o "BCE2_recibidas_consulta_salida.xml" https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fr/SiiFactFRV1SOAP)
URL=${URL%$'\r'}
```

My server is Linux OS so this command it is include in a .sh file. I can assure this works fine because if I launch this shell script in the Terminal, everything goes as expected. But if I launched via "Servoy" I do not get any response. To check if it was something from Servoy not working properly or CURL I have managed to create a really simple .sh file with:

```
URL=$(curl http://www.google.es)
URL=${URL%$'\r'}
```

And works as it should be.

I hope guys you really can help me. I am quite desperate for now.

PS: please excuse my bad English I tried to do my best. If you need any other acclaration please let me know about it.